# Получение List отсутствующих объектов в одном из двух List

Tags: java, list

имеется объект `Comment` c атрибутами

```
Long id;
User author;
String body;
```

В данный момент ко мне в метод приходят 2 списка, нужно проверить есть ли во втором списке значения из первого, и если нет то добавить их в лист и вернуть наружу:

```
private List<Comment> getCommentList(List<Comment> parentComments, List<Comment> childComments){
    List<Comment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(parentComments.stream()
            .filter(pc -> !childComments.contains(pc))
            .collect(toList()));
    return list;
}
```

В данный момент могут приходить одинаковые `body` но разные ID. Я так понимаю что `contains()` тут не подходит потому что объекты по сути приходят разные. Как мне внутрь добавить проверку ещё и по нужным мне атрибутам? Мне нужно решение без переопределения `equals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение с equals()

Просто переопределите `equals()` в объекте Comment, чтобы сравнение происходило именно так, как вам надо, то есть без учёта ID, но с учётом всех остальных полей. `ArrayList#contains` использует `equals()` объекта, так что он будет работать правильно.

Ну учтите, что поле `author` - это тоже объект, а значит, он тоже должен сравниваться корректно *(впрочем, может в вашем случае и сравнение по ссылкам сойдёт)*.

### Решение без equals() со сложностью O(N^2)

Сделайте простой перебор в filter. Вот так:

```
list.addAll(
    parentComments
        .stream()
            .filter(pc -> {
                for (Comment child : childComments) {
                    boolean isAuthorEquals = child.getAuthor().equals(pc.getAuthor());
                    boolean isBodyEquals = child.getBody().equals(pc.getBody());
                    if (isAuthorEquals && isBodyEquals) {
                       return false;
                    }
                }
            })
            .collect(toList()));
```

Что-то вроде этого. Сравниваем свойства вручную. Можно ещё реализовать свой Comparator, чтобы код был почище, я лишь показываю общую идею. **Надо учитывать, что на больших объёмах данных падение производительности может быть очень значительным, и данный вариант ни в коем случае не является оптимальным.** Но если вы точно знаете, что объёмы данных будут небольшими *(а вы это знать наверняка почти точно не сможете)*, то такой вариант может сгодиться.

Comment: Забыл указать что нужно без использования equals, я бы так и сделал, но к сожалению не могу переопределять его.

Comment: @JakeMorgan почему не можете? Это не ваш класс? Ок, сейчас перепишу ответ.

Comment: да, он находится в библиотеке

Comment: @JakeMorgan хотя на самом деле... Знаете, если без equals, то я так не вижу иных вариантов, кроме как реализация со сложностью O(N^2), если это вас устроит, конечно. Если в лоб решать, то всё просто: в фильтре сделайте ещё один обычный цикл и в нём перебор. Вместо equals сравнивайте по конкретным свойствам. Впрочем, сейчас напишу в ответе...

Comment: да меня устроит

Comment: @JakeMorgan подождите, сейчас напишу ответ

Comment: спасибо за помощь